# Congrats (instead of "congratulations") OK?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I'm a British ex-pat, living in the US for forty years. The Americans have started saying "congrats" (for "congratulations") in informal contexts.

To me, this sounds antiquated and upper-class. "I say old chap, oodles of congrats."

Does it still sound that way in the UK, or does it sound normal?

Comment: As an American English speaker (who rarely says *congrats*), what amount of formality and class standing  do you mean when you say *I say old chap, oodles of congrats*? (It does sound particularly English or British to me.)

Comment: As a British English speaker (who _never_ says _congrats_) it sounds dated and over-posh to me.

Comment: As a British English native speaker who does say congrats, *I* think it sounds perfectly fine. Not posh in the slightest but used in less formal registers, eg if my Director was given an award I would offer him my congratulations because he’s many ranks above me and I have no personal relationship with him, but if my colleague at the next desk got an award I’d say ‘congrats’..

Answer (score 1):

As a 'Brit' I hate the use of 'congrats', it sounds insincere, if you can't be bothered to offer 'Congratulations' I think don't bother saying anything. I thought it was coming from America, I papercraft and lots of the kits and sentiment stamps from America read 'Congrats' (and 'gray' instead of the English 'grey').

Comment: Are you using _papercraft_ as a verb? I'm just trying to make sense of the last sentence in your answer.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's used,- but perhaps only in the papercrafting community/industry?  Which, by the way, is huge, so it is used a lot!